# Eiffel: is there a way with do_all or do_if to search for an element in a collection without having to write a whole feature?

Tags: eiffel

```
across
    collection as l_item
until 
    Result /= Void
loop
    if l_item.item.name.is_equal ("foo") then
        Result := l_item.item
    end
end
```

is there a way and if so which one to do something like

```
collection.do_if (agent ...)
```

### an example of use can be:

```
search_item_with_id (an_id: INTEGER)
        -- Moves items cursor if not found is_after
    local
        l_found: BOOLEAN
    do
        from
            items.start
        until
            items.after or l_found
        loop
            l_found := items.item.primary_key = an_id
            if not l_found then
                items.forth
            end
        end
    ensure
        cursor_on_element_if_found: not items.after implies items.item.primary_key = an_id
    end
```

Comment: Yes, you just need to use [Inline Agents] (https://www.eiffel.org/doc/eiffel/ET-_Agents#Inline_agents)

Comment: @javierv Nice thx! but thats an answer not a comment! could you put it or do I have to because you dont have time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, check the following example, with `do_all` and `do_if`  using `inline agents` and routines that are part of the class.

Check the class [LINEAR](https://github.com/EiffelSoftware/EiffelStudio/blob/master/Src/library/base/elks/structures/traversing/linear.e) in `base` Library to learn more about others iterators.

`Collection.do_all (action: PROCEDURE [G])` :Apply the `action` to every item.

`Collection.do_if (action: PROCEDURE [G]; test: FUNCTION [G, BOOLEAN])` :Apply `action` to every item that satisfies `test`.

```
class
    AGENTS_EXAMPLE

create
    make

feature

    make
        do
            print ("%NDo ALL examples: %N")
            example_do_all_with_inline
            example_do_all_with_feature
            print ("%NDo if examples: %N")
            example_do_if_with_inline
            example_do_if_with_features
        end

feature -- Access

    languages: ARRAY [STRING]
            -- Programming languages
        once
            Result := <<"Eiffel", "Ruby", "Python", "C++", "Perl", "Java", "Go", "Rust">>
        end

feature -- Access DO-ALL

    example_do_all_with_inline
            -- with inline
        do
            languages.do_all (agent  (lang: STRING)
                do
                    if lang.same_string_general ("Eiffel") then
                        print ("The OO language with DBC is :) " + lang + "%N")
                    else
                        print ("We don't know what DBC is :( " + lang + "%N")
                    end
                end)
        end

    example_do_all_with_feature
            -- with a feature
        do
            languages.do_all (agent filter_dbc)
        end

    filter_dbc (lang: STRING)
        do
            if lang.same_string_general ("Eiffel") then
                print ("The OO language with DBC is :) " + lang + "%N")
            else
                print ("We don't know what DBC is :( " + lang + "%N")
            end
        end

feature -- Access DO-IF

    example_do_if_with_inline
        do
            languages.do_if (agent  (lang: STRING)
                do
                    print ("The OO language with DBC is :) " + lang + "%N")
                end, agent  (lang: STRING): BOOLEAN
                do
                    if lang.is_case_insensitive_equal ("Eiffel") then
                        Result := True
                    end
                end)
        end

    example_do_if_with_features
        do
            languages.do_if (agent action_print, agent language_dbc_test)
        end

    action_print (a_language: STRING)
        do
            print ("The OO language with DBC is :) " + a_language + "%N")
        end

    language_dbc_test (a_language: STRING): BOOLEAN
        do
            if a_language.is_case_insensitive_equal ("Eiffel") then
                Result := True
            end
        end
end
```

To learn more about inline agents check the following [tutorial](http://eiffel.org/doc/eiffel/ET-_Agents).

Comment: The best practices on stackexchange is always to try to answer the question with a direct answer even if you point to some documentation. I'll complete your answer as soon as I take it into my project. Thx in all cases